# using admin configuration in model file

Tags: python, python-2.7, peewee

The following code is working fine.

## run.py

```
import datetime
from flask import Flask
from peewee import TextField, DateTimeField
from flask_peewee.db import Database
from flask_peewee.auth import Auth
from flask_peewee.admin import Admin, ModelAdmin

# configure database
DATABASE = {
    'name': 'surveyApp.db',
    'engine': 'peewee.SqliteDatabase',
}
DEBUG = True
CSRF_ENABLED = True
SECRET_KEY = 'you-will-never-guess'

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)

db = Database(app)

# from model.user_infos import Note, NoteAdmin

class Note(db.Model):
    message = TextField()
    created = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)

class NoteAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    columns = ('message', 'created',)

# create an Auth object for use with our flask app and database wrapper
auth = Auth(app, db)
admin = Admin(app, auth)
admin.register(Note, NoteAdmin)
admin.setup()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

I am trying to separate the model and register it in admin as well. But it is generating error. All the models are inside 'model' folder.

## Code that generates error:

## run.py (modified)

```
import datetime
from flask import Flask
from peewee import TextField, DateTimeField
from flask_peewee.db import Database
from flask_peewee.auth import Auth
from flask_peewee.admin import Admin, ModelAdmin

# configure database
DATABASE = {
    'name': 'surveyApp.db',
    'engine': 'peewee.SqliteDatabase',
}
DEBUG = True
CSRF_ENABLED = True
SECRET_KEY = 'you-will-never-guess'

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)

db = Database(app)

auth = Auth(app, db)
admin = Admin(app, auth)

from model.user_infos import Note, NoteAdmin # GENERATES IMPORT ERROR
admin.register(Note, NoteAdmin)
admin.setup()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

## model/user_infos.py

```
from run import db, admin

import datetime
from peewee import TextField, DateTimeField
from flask_peewee.admin import ModelAdmin

class Note(db.Model):
    message = TextField()
    created = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)

class NoteAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    columns = ('message', 'created',)
```

model folder contains __init__.py as well

Comment: Do you mean `__init__.py`? `init.py` wont do.

Comment: Yes, its \__init__.py, stackoverflow escaped underscores. "edited my post"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a circular import.

I wrote a blog post: http://charlesleifer.com/blog/structuring-flask-apps-a-how-to-for-those-coming-from-django/

Or you can just follow from the example app: https://github.com/coleifer/flask-peewee/tree/master/example

Comment: Many thanks @coleifer, there was a circular imports. I somehow managed to run application.